# Ensuring 2 linearlayouts that replace each other have the same size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a top section for the app which is mainly logo and stuff, and roughly the bottom half is supposed to be buttons.. In the outer container, i have a layout for the logo, and imageView to create a seperator line between the top and bottom and the bottom layout..

The issue is bottom layout has 2 linearlayouts (one of which is hidden initially) first one is just a spinner and the second one is 2 buttons..

I have achieved the "roughly 1/3 of space) by using layout_weights in the top and bottom linear layout (2 and 1 respectively) but when I hide the spinner and show the 2 buttons in the bottom layout in the code, the seperator line is pushed up.. I want it to stay in the same place (like be where it would be after the 2 buttons show up from the get-go so that it doesn't have to move)

I could probably just add some margin to the original one to match it but i feel like that will cause issues in the future on different devices.

How can I accomplish this feat?

Comment: did you set a weightsum in the layout that contains the top and bottom linearlayouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be neglecting to set `android:layout_height="0dp"` on the LinearLayouts that you set `android:layout_weight="1"` on. If you do this it should fill the space like you want, and you can do `layoutView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `layoutView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to toggle the views.